# Запуск функции после полной загрузки программы

Tags: c#

Есть код

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load_programm();
    }
    void Load_programm(){                
MessageBox.Show("Я принцесса Пупырка");
            }
```

Мне почему то показалось, что функция Load_programm() должна запускаться после полной загрузки самой программы. Но сообщение появляется до загрузки программы. Что поменять?

Comment: вы не доожны выполнять подобную логику в конструкторе. Это нужно делать в обработчике события. Например, **OnLoad**

Comment: private void Form1_OnLoad(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
Теперь не грузится Messagebox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Событие формы Shown вроде то, что нужно. Срабатывает после отображения формы